# Employment history for visa application

Tags: resume, employment-gaps

Suppose, somebody is submitting an application for an immigration visa.

Should someone mention an experience in his `Employment History` if the organization maintains low opinion about him?

Various reasons could be involved,

- Sacked by company for any valid reason
- Engaged in legal battle with the company
- Had feud with his superiors

and so on...

Comment: Post at expatriates.stackexchange.com. How would a feud with your superiors have anything to do with a visa application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it,'s about visa applications rather than workplace application CVs. I agree that it seems a better fit for the expats area

Answer (score 3):

Employment history on such a document is likely intended to simply show that you have a history of employment. Depending on the situation, it is probably unlikely that past employers would be contacted (unless the application involves permission to work, and then it may be more likely).

A private company is unlikely to have the ability to determine with absolute certainty that you worked at XYZ Business for five years, but a foreign state may have the ability through treaties to gain access to tax or other records from your home country that would, in fact, show you paid taxes on income from that company.

It is also likely the application has a bit near the signature section about you attesting to the truthfulness of the document. Signing a document you know to be false is almost certainly (definitely?) universally illegal.

Comment: Also see this question on [expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8841/history-of-employment-while-applying-for-a-visa).